# Como actualizar datos de una BD sql usando Update

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, sqlite

Tengo 2 Bases de Datos, una en español y otra en inglés, la que está en español tiene problemas y no me funciona. Lo que quiero lograr es actualizar 2 tablas de la base de datos en ingles con los mismos datos de la base de datos en español, las tablas son idénticas lo que cambia es el idioma. El nombre de las tablas son name y DESC.

---

cuando clone la BD lo hice sin usar las comillas y me funcionó, con el update nop, y no recuerdo bien como es que se realiza la consulta con update ya q la última vez que hice algo con SQL fue hace 8 años

Comment: Tienes una tabla llamada Nombre? DESC es una palabra reservada para indicar DESCENDENTE en SQL, dudo de que se llame asi. Puedes colocar un ejemplo demostrable o código que haz intentado hacer?

Comment: En si name y DESC son columnas de una de las tablas de la base de datos, la base de datos está compuesta por 3 tablas, la que me interesa es ya tabla texts, en ella existen varias columnas dentro de las que se incluyen name y desc (descripcion)

Comment: update spanish inner join texts on texts.name=spanish.name set spanish.name=texts.name

Comment: Dentro de la misma BD clone la Tabla texts y le puse el nombre spanish, e intenté actualizar las columnas name y desc de la tabla Spanish con los datos de sus similares en la tabla texts(claro hice algunos ajustes en esas columnas)

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando muchas palabras reservadas de mysql como name y desc, se puede hacer pero tienes que utilizar comillas, por ejemplo 'tabla'.'name' (no recuerdo bien que comillas usa mysql, también prueba con ʼ, ` o ")

Esto puede pasar por palabras reservadas o símbolos reservados como el guión medio que en esos casos también va con comillas: 'nombre-tabla'